# getting error 404 when trying to access webapi from IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404

I'm getting 404 when trying to access my webapi from IIS.
heres the `WebApiConfig`:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Serviços e configuração da API da Web

        // Rotas da API da Web
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I've got a controller named `UserControl`.
After I deployed it, try to access "http://localhost:80/chat/api/users"
I brings me that error message.

Debugging on Visual Studio, with the ISS express works fine.

And here is the ISS Manager:
[image: ISS Manager screenshot]

Comment: Are you using IIS vritual folder like `chat` when you deployed it?

Comment: Is the controller name `UserControl` or `UsersController` ? Show us the code of your controller

Answer (score 0):

your controller name is UserControl ? 
i think your controller name should be named UsersController

Answer (score 0):

heres my controller class:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class UsersController : BaseApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<Users> Get()
        {
            List<Users> a = new List<Users>();

            Users u = new Users();
            u.ID = 99;
            u.FULLNAME = "XXX";
            u.USER = "XXX";
            u.PASSWORD = "XXX";

            a.Add(u);

            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the extra details and delete this (its not an Answer)